# How to make sure case insensitive usernames are always accepted by Symfony UserBadge?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-security

I have created a custom `AbstractAuthenticator` subclass in my Symfony 5 project which can process user credentials included in HTTP headers.

```
public function authenticate(Request $request): PassportInterface {
    $userIdentifier = $this->getUserIdentifierFromRequest();
    
    return new Passport(
        new UserBadge($this->userIdentifier),
        new CustomCredentials(
            function ($credentials, UserInterface $user) {
                ...
            },
            
            $credentialFromRequest
        )
    );
}
```

This works fine and when a invalid username is checked a `UserNotFoundException` is thrown by `UserBadge`.

However, I wonder why this implementation is **case insensitive on the given username**?

I checked the Symfony code and `UserBadge` uses the `EntityUserProvider` class which performs a simple `$repository->findOneBy([$this->property => $identifier])` (find by field `email` in my case). After some search I found related answer, which indicate that wether the `find...` operate case sensitive or case insensitive most likely depends on the underlying datebase (MariaDB 10 in my case).

**Is there any way to control wether the username lookup should work case sensitive or not?**

While the case insensitive search is fine in the current project, I would like to make sure, that it stays this way, not matter if I port the project to another machine with another underling database...

Comment: You can take a look at the now defunct FOSUserBundle.  Along with a username they also defined a username_canonical property mostly to keep things case insensitive.  Frankly, the code was quite a mess.  If you ever did move to a case sensitive database then I suspect you will have far bigger issues to contend with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create [a custom User Provider](http://%20https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#creating-a-custom-user-provider).

Then in your provider simply call `strtolower()` on the identifier, and `LOWER()` on the identifier column.

A rather simple implementation, assuming you inject the Entity Manager on your User Provider.

```php
public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $identifier): UserInterface
{
    $user = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u')
            ->from(YourUser::class, 'u')
            ->where('LOWER(u.username) = :username')
            ->setParameter('username', strtolower($identifier))
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

    if (!$user instanceof YourUser::class) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException('No user found for ' . $username);
    }

    return $user;

}
```

Adjust to your application constraints. You can probably move the query itself to the specific entity repository, and create the query there, instead of the provider.

Comment: This sounds very promising, thank you very much!